# CSS modules for react

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to add a css module in the login component. For now, I have a `style.css` stylesheet in the folder `src/styles` and it is loading global styles. But now, I want to customize the login component, so I added a `login.css` file into `componentes/login`:

```
.button {
  background-color: black;
}
```

and my `LoginPage.js` component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Login.css';

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jumbotron col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div className="container">
          <form name="form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" className="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

But my webpack is showing me the following errors:

```
src\components\login\LoginPage.js (2/2)
  ✖  2:20  Parse errors in imported module './Login.css': Unexpected token . (1:1)  import/namespace
  ✖  2:20  Parse errors in imported module './Login.css': Unexpected token . (1:1)  import/default
  !  2:20  Parse errors in imported module './Login.css': Unexpected token . (1:1)  import/no-named-as-default
  !  2:20  Parse errors in imported module './Login.css': Unexpected token . (1:1)  import/no-named-as-default-member
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  noInfo: false,
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
    ]
  }
};
```

for the last, I had a problem when I tried:

```
 <div className="form-group">
   <button className=`${styles.button}`>Login</button>
 </div>

src/components/login/LoginPage.js: JSX value should be eith
er an expression or a quoted JSX text (19:32)
```

How to I set up css modules for react correctly?

**EDIT:**

After the discussion below, I fixed the error loading the class:

```
<div className="form-group">
  <button className={styles.button}>Login</button>
</div>
```

Now, the css is loaded but webpack keeps showing the same errors and warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to import actual CSS into your JS without having gone through the transformation into [ICSS](https://github.com/css-modules/icss) first

Your webpack loader simply needs to be set up for CSS modules. To do this you need to add `modules` and optionally a template for the localised classnames.

Change your CSS loader to:

```
{test: /(\.css)$/, loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'}
```

This will tell webpack to precompile the CSS into ICSS before the import, which becomes just a JS object telling it how to map your `button` class name into the dynamic localised class name string `LoginPage__button___ab123`

You should then add classNames via this imported object as you were first trying, although the interpolated string is not needed unless adding multiple classes

```
<button className={styles.button}>Login</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error hint, you can write this way:

```
<div className="form-group">
  <button className={styles.button}>Login</button>
</div>
```

Because strings quoted by **`something ${var}`** are treated as variables, which need extra calculation before  parsed into ES5 js code (while string looks like **'rawString'** or **"rawString2"** needn't).

Comment: Yup, it solves the problem but not the import of the stylesheet

Comment: I tried but it keeps saying the thing about `Unexpected token` in the `Login.css`

Comment: @FacundoGFlores For css grammar, if you want to set button's style, you should use `button {background: white}` instead of using class selector `.button {background: white}`, `.button` works for <div className='button'>. And, I have no idea about your webpack problem :(

Comment: And `.form-group { button { background: 'white' } }` could be better. (still no idea about your webpack error...)

Comment: Yeah, the last one is better. I am searching for an answer about webpack, and this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1754 is a possible solution, but I tried putting `require.extensions['.css'] = () => {
  return;
};` in my `index.js` file and still giving me the same error for the `css` but now says me: `WARNING in ./src/index.js
require.extensions is not supported by webpack`

Comment: @FacundoGFlores I noticed your `login.css` file is under `components/` folder while your `style.css` is under `src/index`. If you can load your `style.css` file correctly, could you have an experiment: move `login.css` to the same folder with `style.css` (maybe src/styles) and import `login.css` from '../../xxxx'

Comment: Yes! it works! How can I set up webpack for loading stylesheets from components folders?

Comment: @FacundoGFlores Wow! I think something is wrong with your `entry` config: `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')`, but I'm not sure about how to solve that by editing webapck. One possible solution is: put all your code & css files under `src/` and set the entry to `src` :)

Comment: Oh my... I did not see the webpack error... it was always working, but I had to refresh the page... the css is loaded but webpack is showing the error